# mediawiki common css

Tags: css, mediawiki

I installed Mediawiki on our web server and at the moment the design is lacking a bit. I am not satisfied with the layout of my tables. In short they are ugly.

I took a look a wikipedia tables and they are using the class="wikitable" in the table declaration. After some research I found the page http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css were code is provided to improve the layout. You have to create a new page in your wiki installation and add the provided CSS-Code and save it. After reloading and emptying the Cache of your browser (SHIFT + Reload-Button for FF) you should be able to use class="wikitable" in your table definitions. It is not working for me. Does anyone know what I missed?

regards, Usurper

Answer (score 1):

> Look at the HTML source of your wiki
>   pages to see if these pages are loaded
>   at all (note that Common.js is called
>   from
>   ?title=-&action=raw&smaxage=0&gen=js
>   "site js" URL. If they are called,
>   check the content inside.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_talk:Common.css#Common.css_does_not_seem_to_have_any_impact